# How do I fix this TypeError in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, ntp

I'm attempting to create an NTP client that will eventually print out the time in "Mon May 10 07:29:23 EDT 2019" format.

```
host = "pool.ntp.org"; 
port = 123; 
address = ( host, port ); 
data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'; 

client = socket.socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM ); 

client.sendto( data, address );
```

I keep getting the following error for the sendto line:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm having a lot of issues understanding this error, so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `'\x1b' + 47 * '\0'` is a str, which represents the Unicode characters U+001B, U+0000, …; use bytes `b'\x1b' + 47 * b'\0'` instead.

Comment: You can't send a string over a socket. You can only send bytes. Convert the string to bytes by choosing an encoding for it, or better yet, construct it as bytes to begin with.